# Reducing repeated HTML code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to reduce the amount of repeated code I have in my application. 
A friend suggested putting the block that is repeated into a separate file and including it each time it is needed, whilst passing in a different variable, but another friend said this might not be the best way to do it.

I've been trying to find a good solution but the only thing I have found so far requires using a template engine which I'd like to avoid if possible as my application is only small. 
So theoretically the block of HTML I want repeating could look like this.

```
<p class="blockwrapper">Bunch of other code</p>
```

And then each time the code is repeated I'd like to pass a new variable into "blockwrapper".

I don't know if it's best to do this through JS or PHP.

Comment: Well, I guess the only answer to your question is, "Yes, you can do something like this with JavaScript or PHP."  How you'd do it really depends on how you're building the page currently, how that variable changes, how it drives the difference in the output, etc.  All you're really asking now is "can it be done" to which the answer is "yes".

Comment: I wrote an answer but just know that this is one of many. It's up to you if you do templating on the server-side or the client-side and if you're planning to scale this project out at any point then you'll want to look into a templating engine or using something like KnockoutJS if it matches your needs.

Comment: You should try AngularJS. Easy to learn and really reduces HTML code

Comment: @David I don't think it's very constructive to answer a question with the least possible amount of information. It's clear that OP is trying to learn the basics of constructing a dynamic webpage, even if it's possible to parse the question as a trivial yes/no.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut: That's nice.  It's probably worth noting that I didn't post an answer.  Feel free to scroll down the page and observe this for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A templating engine would be best but if you're not planning on having many different variables and relatively short code chunks then you could put the code in a template block then perform a replace on the variable names.

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
<!-- I'm replacing blockwrapper with #value# because it's less
likely to cause a collision -->
<p class="#value#">Bunch of other code</p>
</script>
```

---

```
function createHTML(templateID, value) {
    var html = document.getElementById(templateID).innerHTML;
    html = html.replace(/#value#/g, value);
    return html;
}
```

This will create a new set of HTML code from your "template" replacing all occurrences of `"#value#"` with `value`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was aiming for. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with JavaScript - you are basically providing the user's browser with a bunch of pieces and a recipe for how to build the page from those pieces. That's going to make the page feel a bit slower for the user, though, because they have to load the page and then wait while their browser executes your instructions. There are cases where this is absolutely a good solution, though, and if you're interested I'd suggest researching a JS template engine like Handlebars which makes it much easier to do this. @Mike-C's answer is a good description of how you can do it without a template engine.

For a very simple case like you are describing, I would suggest using PHP. You could make a function like this:

```
<?php
    function renderBlockWrapper($blockWrapperContents) {
        include('blockwrapper.html.php');
    }
?>
```

And then in blockwrapper.html.php* you could have:

```
<p class="blockwrapper"><?php echo $blockWrapperContents ?></p>
```

And finally in your base file, you could create lots of block wrapper elements like this:

```
<?php renderBlockWrapper('Hello world'); ?>
<?php renderBlockWrapper('Hello again'); ?>
<?php renderBlockWrapper('Here I am a third time!'); ?>
```

Which would output

```
<p class="blockwrapper">Hello world</p>
<p class="blockwrapper">Hello again</p>
<p class="blockwrapper">Here I am a third time!</p>
```

* In case you don't already know this: It is a common convention if you have a file of one type that generates a file of a different type to combine their file endings like this. So .html.php denotes a PHP file that generates an HTML file.